# Eventhandler "bug" using VB.NET with windows forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

i have the following code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)

    Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = &H112
    Const SC_SCREENSAVE As Integer = &HF140

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
    If bloqueado = 0 Then
        If m.Msg = WM_SYSCOMMAND AndAlso m.WParam.ToInt32 = SC_SCREENSAVE Then
            Timer2.Start()
            inicio = Now
            pausa = pausa + 1
            AddHandler Application.Idle, AddressOf Application_Idle
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Idle(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim newitem As ListViewItem
    Dim diferença As TimeSpan

    'MsgBox(Now.ToString)'
    Debug.Print(Now.ToString)
    fim = Now
    diferença = fim - inicio
    Timer2.Stop()
    newitem = New ListViewItem
    newitem.Text = pausa
    newitem.SubItems.Add(inicio.ToLongTimeString)
    newitem.SubItems.Add(fim.ToLongTimeString)
    newitem.SubItems.Add(diferença.ToString.Substring(0, 8))
    ListView1.Items.Add(newitem)
    parcial = parcial & pausa & vbTab & vbTab & inicio.ToLongTimeString & vbTab & vbTab & fim.ToLongTimeString _
         & vbTab & vbTab & diferença.ToString.Substring(0, 8) & vbTab & vbTab & "   screensaver" & System.Environment.NewLine
    RemoveHandler Application.Idle, AddressOf Application_Idle
End Sub
```

Basically the first part detect when screensaver activates and creates a application.idle event handler and the second part, when activity is detected a bunch of code is run and the handler removed.

It's all works fine except for one point:

As you can see i have inicio = now when screensaver becomes active and fim = now when activity is detected (when screensaver becomes inactive), so i should have 2 differente times, but if i have it like i posted the 2 datetime will be the same. If you notice i have a msgbox displaying the now (when screensaver stops) in comment, if i take it out of comment the 2 datetimes will be differente and correct (i used a cronometer to make sure of the results)

Now my questions:
Why does it need the messagebox for the `now` to be updated and why doesn't it work it debug.print?

Is there a way to solve this problem/update the `now` var, without having to use a messagebox (i wouldn't like for the app to have pop-up messages)

If i really have to use msgbox for this purpose is there a way for it not to send the pop-up or to autoclick ok right after so it disappears instantly?

EDIT:

I have been searching and i found this code:

```
Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Public Function IsSNRunning() As Boolean
        IsSNRunning = (FindWindow("WindowsScreenSaverClass", vbNullString) <> 0)
    End Function

    Private Sub Timer3_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
        If IsSNRunning() Then
            'Screen Saver Is Running
        Else
            Timer3.Stop()
            code
        End If
End Sub
```

i used `Timer3.Start()` when in the part that captures the start of the screensaver, my idea being if i start the timer when i know the screensaver if on, then when i get IsSNRunning as false is when the screensaver stops running, but it doesn't work, any ideas why?

Comment: *fim = now when activity is detected* How does `Application.Idle` alert you of activity? *Why does it need the messagebox for the now to be updated and why doesn't it work it debug.print?* Presumably the messagebox runs straight away (`Application.Idle` is an extremely common thing) but blocks the code from continuing until you move the mouse, clearing the screensaver and seeing the messagebox. When you close the message box, the `Debug.Print` code runs with the current time.

Comment: application_idle is an event related to activity

Comment: It's related to the application about to become "idle", so no activity... Make your event handler beep instead of showing a message box.

Comment: hmm. then how can i detect activity? like the mouse moving or clocking or key pressing? so that i know when the screesaver ends?

Comment: How long do you think `pausa = pausa + 1` and `AddHandler Application.Idle, AddressOf Application_Idle` take to execute? I'm suspecting it's much faster than what you can capture in the two calls to `Now`, especially since the first is a simple increment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3953364/242520

Comment: Hmm. this is indeed troublesome, is there a way to use SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING on VB?

Comment: @Newbee: That's a separate question, and should be posted as one. Asking new questions in comments is not how SO works.

Comment: Just scroll down the page... http://stackoverflow.com/a/9858981/242520

Comment: Sorry but i'm not being able to make it work, the code on that question is C# and i'm using VB

Comment: Translate the code...

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/e6s2ofqpavubwup1ppffg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i'll thank you guys for the help, like you said `application.idle` doesn't work, with you help i got this solution i VB:

```
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> Public Shared Function SystemParametersInfo(uAction As UInteger, _
    uParam As UInteger, ByRef lpvParam As Boolean, fWinIni As Integer) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function
' Check if the screensaver is busy running.'
Public Shared Function IsScreensaverRunning() As Boolean
    Const SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING As Integer = 114
    Dim isRunning As Boolean = False

    If Not SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, 0, isRunning, 0) Then
        ' Could not detect screen saver status...'
        Return False
    End If

    If isRunning Then
        ' Screen saver is ON.'
        Return True
    End If

    ' Screen saver is OFF.'
    Return False
End Function


Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)

    Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = &H112
    Const SC_SCREENSAVE As Integer = &HF140

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
    If bloqueado = 0 Then
        If m.Msg = WM_SYSCOMMAND AndAlso m.WParam.ToInt32 = SC_SCREENSAVE Then
            Timer2.Start()
            Timer3.Enabled = True
            Timer3.Start()
            'here we that that the screensaver started running so we start a timer'
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer3_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick

    If IsScreensaverRunning() Then
        'Screen Saver Is Running'
    Else
        Timer3.Stop()
        Timer3.Enabled = False
        'Screen Saver Is not Running'
    End If

End Sub
```

Because the timer only starts running when the screensaver is running we know that when you get timer3.stop is when the screensaver stopped running

Important, don't put a msgbox before the timer stop because it wont work, the pop-up will show and it wont get to the stop so innumerous pop-up will appear (yeah... i made that mistake :S)

Again, thanks for helping me and hope it will help someone in the future

Answer (score 1):

Doing anything with Application.Idle is a lost cause.  Not only does your app go idle *immediately* after the screen saver activates, you also never stop being idle while it is running.  The screen saver switches the active desktop to a dedicated secure desktop, none of the running programs will ever get any input, not until it de-activates.

You can observe the desktop switch, the SystemEvents.SessionSwitch event fires.

Do note the considerable lack of practical usefulness of code like this.  Curiosity is okay but there are always a lot of things to learn.  The screen saver should be at the bottom of your list.